# C++ display text left and right in same row

Tags: c++, formatting, cout

I want to output a whole formatted console line (80 characters) in C++.

It should look like this:

`Some things on the left side                        some other on the right side`

The data contains two iterator functions that return std::string and fixed texts. Something like this:

```
std::cout << (*some_iterator)->getID() << " some text:" << LOTSOFSPACES << (*some_other_iterator)->getName() << " some more text.";
```

Outcome should always be 80 characters.

I tried messing around with std::setw and std::setfill, std::left and std::right,  using a stringstream and calculating the spaces I have to create. But nothing really works and most ideas just destroyed the output completely.

Any ideas? Unfortunately I am not allowed to use external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can tell for sure both parts are always less than 40 characters (or they can be split in two columns in any other way), you could do it like this:

```
std::string firstPart = (*some_iterator)->getID() + " some text:";
std::string secondPart = (*some_other_iterator)->getName() + " some more text.";
std::cout << std::setw(40) << std::left <<  firstPart 
          << std::setw(40) << std::right << secondPart;
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u9ITHvg7bmFa7rVc)

More versatile solution would be to simply calculate the spacing between strings and insert it manually. This doesn't require having columns of known length:

```
std::string firstPart = (*some_iterator)->getID() + " some text:";
std::string secondPart = (*some_other_iterator)->getName() + " some more text.";
std::size_t spacingSize = 80 - firstPart.length() - secondPart.length();
    //Add some code to check if spacingSize is not negative!
std::cout << firstPart << std::string(spacingSize, ' ') << secondPart;
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BQauCLoLkVRwR5kV)

Comment: It doesn't work because the strings I am using are not constant. They consist of an iterator and a const portion. I think it calculates the wrong length because of this fact. The output gets garbled up.

Comment: Iterators do not make any difference. As long as `getID()` and `getName()` return valid `std::string` (and total sum of characters is `< 80`), you should be good. I editted the code to make it more fitting to your example.

Comment: Okay. My mistake. One iterator returned int instead of std::string. I just used the wrong member function because they got similar names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the coursor at the position.
First you have to add library:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Now you can use function:

```
COORD c;
c.X = x_coordinate;
c.Y = y_coordinate;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
```